# https does't work but http works fine

Tags: http, https

When I try to download a file from internet, I found the same link download fail with https but success with http.

e.g.

```
 wget https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/gear4/fileSequence0.ts
--2014-01-31 16:01:05--  https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/gear4/fileSequence0.ts
Resolving devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net (devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net)... 23.73.64.225
Connecting to devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net (devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net)|23.73.64.225|:443... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net’ is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net’ hasn't got a known issuer.
```

But if I change the https to http, it works fine:

```
wget https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/gear4/fileSequence0.ts
--2014-01-31 16:01:05--  https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/gear4/fileSequence0.ts
Resolving devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net (devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net)... 23.73.64.225
Connecting to devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net (devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net)|23.73.64.225|:443... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net’ is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net’ hasn't got a known issuer.
e12714@e12714-mac00:~/Downloads/tmp/20140131_180312$ wget http://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/gear4/fileSequence0.ts
--2014-01-31 16:01:46--  http://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/gear4/fileSequence0.ts
Resolving devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net (devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net)... 23.73.64.225
Connecting to devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net (devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net)|23.73.64.225|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1878120 (1.8M) [video/mp2t]
Saving to: ‘fileSequence0.ts.1’

100%[==============================================================================>] 1,878,120   9.85MB/s   in 0.2s   

2014-01-31 16:01:47 (9.85 MB/s) - ‘fileSequence0.ts.1’ saved [1878120/1878120]
```

What's the reason the https download fail?

Comment: the server has to support https, you cannot simply put https and get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the wget --no-check-certificate parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose because https is protocol for ssl, it should be supported on server, and also if supported you need to negotiate parameters with handshake protocol, alert protocol, cipher and record.